# Is it possible to index labels in Titan?

Tags: titan

When I run a query like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel("myDefinedLabel").values("myKey").next()
```

It prints

```
20:46:30 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - 
Query requires iterating over all vertices [(~label = myDefinedLabel)].
For better performance, use indexes
```

So, I guess to solve this issue, I need to index the label. Is there anyway to do this?

I tried doing the normal procedure to create an index described [here in Titan docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) but the label is not a regular property key to index.

Assuming I want to create a composite index for labels, how to do it?

Comment: I'm wondering if it makes sense to add the labels as an attribute that you could index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titan [doesn't allow you to index labels](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1349a5edd1149a00da6a37a4584aed25a8164a14/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/types/system/SystemTypeManager.java#L13), and [according to the devs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/f2HX9hUvBuA) it isn't something they're interested in enabling.